# How can i make this JS code shorter?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
 $('#fadeinright').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeinright");
    }
});
$('#fadeinleft').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeinleft");
    }
});
     $('#fadeintop').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeintop");
    }
});
$('#fadeinbottom').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeinbottom");
    }
});
$('#simplefadein').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $(this).removeClass("simplefadein");
    }
});
```

Does some one knows how to make it shorter?
i am about to add more classes, and im not sure its the right way of doing the code.

here is an example how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/nbgdzspy/35/

Comment: If this code works it is probably better placed under http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: will [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nbgdzspy/36/) work?

Comment: Your overall approach seems strange. Why does each element belong to a class with the same name as the element-ID? And why do you then want to remove the class? I think you may have an XY problem of some sort . . .

Comment: Hello Danny im sorry for being novice, but i dont write questions so that people could tell me that i cant code, I ask question so that i could learn. Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My variant

```
$('#fadeinright, #fadeinleft, #fadeintop, #fadeinbottom, #fadeinbig, #fadeinsmall').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $(this).removeClass($(this).attr('id'));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
['fadeinright', 'fadeinleft', 'fadeintop', 'fadeinbottom', 'fadeinbig', 'fadeinsmall'].forEach(function (name) {
    $('#' + name).waypoint(function (direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $(this).removeClass(name);
        }
    }, {
        offset: '100%'
    });
});
```